# Get total size of a list of files in UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to run a `find` command that will find a certain list of files and then iterate through that list of files to run some operations. I also want to find the total size of all the files in that list.

I'd like to make the list of files FIRST, then do the other operations. Is there an easy way I can report just the total size of all the files in the list?

In essence I am trying to find a one-liner for the 'total_size' variable in the code snippet below:

```
#!/bin/bash
loc_to_look='/foo/bar/location'

file_list=$(find $loc_to_look -type f -name "*.dat" -size +100M)

total_size=???

echo 'total size of all files is: '$total_size

for file in $file_list; do
         # do a bunch of operations
done
```

Comment: You can use `printf "%p %s\n"` in your `find` command to show the name + size.

Comment: @fedorqui If her version of `find` supports `-printf`. Some form of `-exec stat -f '%z' {} \;` (depending on your system's implementation of `stat`) would work as well.

Comment: @fedorqui: also you'd then have to split out the filenames and sizes before the for loop...

Comment: Storing a list of file names in a flat string is not recommended anyway, since you can't cope with file names containing whitespace easily.

Comment: Assuming GNU **find** which provides a very handy `-printf` option, `printf "%'d\n" $(( 0 $(find /foo/bar/location -type f -printf "+ %s") ))`.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You should simply be able to pass `$file_list` to `du`:

```
du -ch $file_list | tail -1 | cut -f 1
```

`du` options:

- `-c` display a total
- `-h` human readable (i.e. 17M)

`du` will print an entry for each file, followed by the total (with `-c`), so we use `tail -1` to trim to only the last line and `cut -f 1` to trim that line to only the first column.

Comment: thanks @sanmiguel! i put the command in backticks for the variable :D

Comment: This is a nice answer, but please remember that `du` prints actual disk usage rounded up to a multiple of (usually) 4 KB instead of logical file size.  `for i in {0..9}; do echo -n $i > $i.txt; done; du -ch *.txt` => `40K total` instead of `10 total`.

Comment: You're right, although in this case the ±4KB difference becomes negligible as we're only dealing with files over 100MB... ;-)

Comment: Also, check your version of `du`. If you are using GNU tools, you might be able to add `--apparent-size` to the `du` options to get the same size listing that `ls` displays.

Comment: What if the files name in the $files_list contain space? I've tried escaping space with `\ ` but no luck.

Comment: @sanmiguel: Can you update your answer to include the recommendation for `--apparent-size`?

Comment: Note that `du` on SunOS does not accept the -c flag.

Comment: for those like me: if you want to give the list from a file replace `$file_list` with `\`cat file.txt\``

Answer (score 52):

Methods explained here have hidden bug. When file list is long, then it exceeds limit of shell comand size. Better use this one using du:

```
find <some_directories> <filters> -print0 | du <options> --files0-from=- --total -s|tail -1
```

find produces null ended file list, du takes it from stdin and counts.
this is independent of shell command size limit.
Of course, you can add to du some switches to get logical file size, because by default du told you how physical much space files will take.

But I think it is not question for programmers, but for unix admins :) then for stackoverflow this is out of topic.

Comment: This is by far the best answer. No need for awk, or shell variables.

Comment: We can remove `-print0` and `--files0-from=-` and replace them with a call to `xargs`, e.g. `find . | xargs du`.

Comment: with xargs it calls du command many times, then it will be much slower, and will higher utilizes resources. otherwise, it will not prevent properly run, when any file name will contain any new line character. then find with xargs should have 'null end' option, for xargs it will be --null or -0 (numerical zero) switch.

Comment: Or `find <some_directories> <filters> -exec du -ch "{}" + | tail -1 | cut -f 1`

Comment: with exec option, it will not work with parallel, then this will be slower. remember about -print0 and others, because you newer know what special chars are in directories and files names.

Comment: Someone mark this the right answer! Way better than any of the others.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without `-print0`? I have `files.txt` all over my file system that I generate with newline instead of null termination. Usually I use `xargs -d'\n'`but I can't get du to sum the sizes which is frustrating.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. you should filter files.txt on the fly by awk or tr, newline to null ended on the fly. of course names with new line characters will be broken with that procedure. fortunately, names including new line are very rare

Comment: For those who might need it,  if you have a files.txt listing the files you can pipe that through tr to convert newline to null.
`cat files.txt | tr '\n' '\0' | du -h --files0-from=- --total -s | tail -1`
will output the list of files, convert newlines to null, pipe it in to du.  I used this to successfully list total size of 46,800 files.

Answer (score 6):

This code adds up all the bytes from the trusty ls for all files (it excludes all directories... apparently they're 8kb per folder/directory)

```
cd /; find -type f -exec ls -s \; | awk '{sum+=$1;} END {print sum/1000;}'
```

**Note:** Execute as root. Result in megabytes.

Comment: The result of find ls gives something like:

`1172471810      4 drwx------  20  uname  eccc_cmdn     4096 Mar  1 20:12 /file`

So the correct formula use the 7th column:

`find -type f -exec ls -s \; | awk '{sum+=$7;} END {print sum/1024;}'`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `du` is that it adds up the size of the directory nodes as well. It is an issue when you want to sum up only the file sizes. (Btw., I feel strange that `du` has no option for ignoring the directories.)

In order to add the size of files under the current directory (recursively), I use the following command:

```
ls -laUR | grep -e "^\-" | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f5 | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

How it works: it lists all the files recursively (`"R"`), including the hidden files (`"a"`) showing their file size (`"l"`) and without ordering them (`"U"`). (This can be a thing when you have many files in the directories.) Then, we keep only the lines that start with "-" (these are the regular files, so we ignore directories and other stuffs). Then we merge the subsequent spaces into one so that the lines of the tabular aligned output of `ls` becomes a single-space-separated list of fields in each line. Then we `cut` the 5th field of each line, which stores the file size. The `awk` script sums  these values up into the `sum` variable and prints the results.

Comment: In some shells, you can display the result with thousand separators: 
`printf "%'.0f\n" $(ls -laUR | grep -e "^\-" | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f5 | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}')`

Comment: What's the advantage of using cut to get the 5th word, why not use $5 inside the awk statement?

Answer (score 1):

`ls -l | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f <field number>` is something I use a lot.

The 5th field is the size. Put that command in a for loop and add the size to an accumulator and you'll get the total size of all the files in a directory. Easier than learning AWK. Plus in the command substitution part, you can grep to limit what you're looking for (^- for files, and so on).

```
total=0

for size in $(ls -l | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 5) ; do
  total=$(( ${total} + ${size} ))
done

echo ${total}
```

Comment: answer may be correct but for others to understand please add some text to describe in nice way.

Answer (score 1):

The method provided by @Znik helps with the bug encountered when the file list is too long.

However, on Solaris (which is a Unix), `du` does not have the `-c` or `--total` option, so it seems there is a need for a counter to accumulate file sizes.

In addition, if your file names contain special characters, this will not go too well through the pipe ([Properly escaping output from pipe in xargs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385466/properly-escaping-output-from-pipe-in-xargs)
).

Based on the initial question, the following works on Solaris (with a small amendment to the way the variable is created):

```
file_list=($(find $loc_to_look -type f -name "*.dat" -size +100M))
printf '%s\0' "${file_list[@]}" | xargs -0 du -k | awk '{total=total+$1} END {print total}'
```

The output is in KiB.

Comment: no, there is not a bug :) with list of files transfered by pipe, it is transferredn line by line using some pipe buffer. you're right, Solaris does not have got some options. but there is no barier, to install GNU shell utils for solaris. Unfortunately Solaris currently is step by step exotic system, It is under Oracle hands, and is so expensive. Many systems has been replaced by intel platform with linux because TCO is much lower, and by high compatibility with software used for solaris.