# Calculate the total size of all files from a generated folders list with full PATH

Tags: linux, ls, du

I have a list containing multiple directories with the full PATH:

```
/mnt/directory_1/sub_directory_1/

/mnt/directory_2/

/mnt/directory_3/sub_directory_3/other_directories_3/
```

I need to calculated what the total size is of this list.

From [Get total size of a list of files in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989860/get-total-size-of-a-list-of-files-in-unix)

```
du -ch $file_list | tail -1 | cut -f 1
```

This was the closest of an answer I could find but gave me the following error message:

> bash: /bin/du: Argument list too long

Comment: `I have a list containing` How is the list stored? `$file_list` - What is the content of variable `$file_list`?

Comment: Iterate over the list and sum the results.

Comment: What @KamilCuk and William said: Also:  "human readable" (`-h`) doesn't really offer itself to arithmetic if there's a varied kinds of units (e.g. some K/M/G in the output).

Comment: @KamilCuk the $file_list is the name of the file. 
I run it like this:
du -ch 'cat file_list.txt` | tail -1 | cut -f 1

The content is the full path mentioned above. Each of these directories and sub-directories contain a mix of files with different extensions. I have on pastebin an example of the structure (small scale): https://pastebin.com/xEAj9csy

On this example it works but when you have too many files (100k) I get the error:
bash: /bin/du: Argument list too long

There is a limitation when using this approach and I'm looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use backticks `. Use `$(..)` instead.

Do not use:

```
command $(cat something)
```

this is a common **anti**-pattern. It works for simple cases, fails for many more, because the result of `$(...)` undergoes word splitting and filename expansion.

Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net

If you want to "run a command with argument from a file" use `xargs` or write a loop.  Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 . Also `xargs` will handle too many arguments by itself. And I would also add `-s` to `du`. Try:

```
xargs -d'\n' du -sch < file_list.txt | tail -1 | cut -f 1
```

test on [repl bash](https://replit.com/@kamilcukrowski/GainsboroBouncyTrapezoids#main.sh)

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk, this might be a stupid follow up but your solution give me another error:  
du: cannot access ‘./mnt/directory_1\r’: No such file or directory
It adds and \r to the end of each directory.

From the site https://linuxhint.com/bash_xargs_command_by_example/
I tried the follow but with the same result:  
xargs -i -d '\n' du -sch {} < file_list.txt | tail -1 | cut -f 1

I will keep looking into it. "Dziękuję" for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Your file has dos line endings. Remove them.

Comment: `error: xargs: error closing file` - you edited or removed the file while `xargs` was running `du: invalid zero-length file name` your input file has empty lines. Remove them.